# How can I modify 1 key value pair out of 4 in a properties file?

Tags: java, properties-file

I have 4 key value pairs in a properties file and I want to modify the value of 1 key. How can I do so without affecting the other key value pairs?

Comment: Load the properties file, set the value of the key to something else, save it again... have you tried any of that yet?

Comment: You should go for the `Properties` class in java. Search for how to use that. Then if you had any problem, ask it here in along with the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of loading a properties file, manipulating a value and storing again.

```
try {
    File file = new File("YOUR PATH");

    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(input);
    input.close();

    properties.setProperty("YOUR_KEY", "YOUR_VALUE");

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    properties.store(output, null);
    output.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it just worked on the first attempt (Y)